# Passing variable in Group By in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

How can I pass variable in Group BY expression.Here is my code.
and from @Varientsku I want to pass column name

```
Create Proc spIsUnique
@varientsku nvarchar(max) output
As
Begin
select @varientsku,
IIf (count(*)>1,'Dublicate','True') as Total from product group by  
@varientsku
End.
```

and I get this error.
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
Help me to solve this

Comment: There's a very long list of duplicates, I just added 3 but searching for `[sql-server] Parameterize identifiers` yields a very long list of questions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic sql

```
      EXEC ('select '+@varientsku+',
                    IIf (count(*)>1,''Duplicate'',''True'') as Total 
            from product 
            group by '+@varientsku)
```

**Note :** Make sure `@varientsku` is sanitized, this code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: SQL injection alert

Comment: @TT. True, but that would depend on who is calling this proc.

Comment: @TT. True but there is not other way you can get this done

Comment: @TT. Hope its fine now ;)

Comment: Sure, if the length of the contents of @varientsku is 128 characters or less.

Comment: if there are multiple columns, it's possible to split them and check every column in schema

Comment: @TT. - If `@varientsku` isn't a column name, dynamic sql isn't going execute. Or what am i missing here

Comment: the only problem is expressions... like CASE WHEN ... END

Comment: @Anton - If you are sure that `@varientsku` is sanitized then you can remove the `if` condition and `quotename` and execute the sql directly

Comment: My opinion is that what is asked in the question is the wrong way to go about this. Perhaps if the "columns" or "expressions" were in a table variable, then this could be done somewhat sensibly. In any case, QUOTENAME takes as parameter values of type SYSNAME, which is equivalent to NVARCHAR(128). Expressions longer than that, would be clipped to 128 characters.

Comment: @Anton - From where `@varientsku` variable is generated. Edit : Lol I thought you are the OP

Comment: @TT. - Got it.. Quotename cannot be used, as per the previous comment from OP, even case expression can be passed..

Comment: Edited:- I want to passed column name from @varientsku